# How to convert python xgboost model to spark xgboost model?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a python xgboost model I would like to run on data in azure databricks (spark).

In my first cell, I load my python model

```
%python
import pickle
python_model = pickle.load(open("/dbfs/tmp/xgb-rts-python/v1/harmony_xgb_v1.pkl", 'rb'))
```

Then in my next cell, I have

```
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.XGBoost
val df_test = spark.read.load("/tmp/xgb-rts/df_test_dense.csv")
val xgbClassificationModel_ = XGBoostClassificationModel.load(xgbClassificationModelPath)
val results = xgbClassificationModel_.transform(df_test)
```

What I want to do is also

```
val results = python_model.transform(df_test)
```

Is there a way to do this? I just want to run the python_model on df_test in spark.

Comment: have you tried converting the `df_test` to `pandas df` and run the model on it, and convert it back to Spark DF should you need to do any additional spark processing on it.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that...but there's so much data that the model run times out.